# Cant exclude tags using AxeBuilder with Axe-Selenium-Java

Tags: java, selenium, accessibility

I am trying to implement [axe-selenium-java](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-selenium-java) into our Selenium automation framework and am having a problem with the excludes function. Essentially it seems to ignore the item(s) I ask it to exclude and just evaluates the whole page.

As you can see its pretty simple what Im looking for, Im asking it to exclude the header and evaluate everything inside the main tags as the header content it looked after by another team.
Example method below:

```
public void testAccessibility(String method) {
    JSONObject responseJSON = new AXE.Builder(driver, scriptUrl)
            .include("main")
            .exclude("header")
            .analyze();

    JSONArray violations = responseJSON.getJSONArray("violations");

    if (violations.length() == 0) {
        assertTrue("No violations found", true);
    } else {
        AXE.writeResults(method, responseJSON);
        assertTrue(AXE.report(violations), false);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this wouldnt be working?

Comment: Looks like Axe/webdriverjs include and exclude tests are only for css classes on html: https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-webdriverjs#axebuilderexcludeselectorstring maybe it's the same for axe-selenium-java?

Comment: just a quick one, does the include / exclude not chain? i.e. if you include 'main' does 'header' not need to be *within* 'main' for it to work? I only say this as normally your 'header' would sit outside of your 'main'. The link you gave says 'CSS selectors' so 'main' and 'header' are perfectly valid CSS selectors. I could be wrong, just a thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with Axe which will be resolved in the next release.

I was informed on gitter here:
https://gitter.im/dequelabs/axe-core?at=5e60f792cb91b5224f1134c8

Having a look on GitHub, this appears to be the issue.
https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-selenium-java/issues/42

Comment: care to cite the bug report as a link, otherwise nobody will be able to track whether this was actually fixed (plus it adds credibility to your answer).